# Laravel with datetimepicker

Tags: laravel, datetimepicker

I've configured by bower and installed bootstrap-datetimepicker like it says in the [docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

I've set the bower **directory** in **resources/assets/bower**. After that I  wanted to include the installed components inside of my blade. As far as I know the best way to do that is to use **laravel-mix**. I opened the **app.js** and **added** the following lines of code

```
require('../assets/bower/moment/moment')
require('../assets/bower/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker')
```

I did the same with **app.scss** file and added

```
@import "../assets/bower/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/sass/bootstrap-datetimepicker-build";
```

This is the console output when I run `npm run dev`

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    $bs-datetimepicker-active-bg: $btn-primary-bg !default;
                                 ^
          Undefined variable.
  ╷
7 │ $bs-datetimepicker-active-bg: $btn-primary-bg !default;
  │                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  resources\assets\bower\eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker\src\sass\_bootstrap-datetimepicker.scss 7:31  @import
  stdin 3:9
```

As far as I can see this is a **bootstrap variable** but even when I included bootstrap variable that didn't help.

I'm stuck for hours now and I have no clue what to do. Even after i compiled successfully app.js. It still says taht `custom.js:117 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`. I have my app.js included in the blade **before** I included my custom.js so It's supose to be working since it's loaded after it.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this CDN**

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

**Write in your  AJAX Code**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datetimepicker1" ).datepicker({

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please mark as verified this answer if it's help for you thank you..